# In Spring Portlet MVC, how can I redirect the action to resource url instead of render url

Tags: jquery, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

In my portlet, I am using jQuery to open a dialog window.  In the url of the dialog, I am using a Resource URL to retrieve the html that represents a form.  When I call submit on the dialog-based form, it submits to the portlet via ActionMapping.

The problem is how can I simply redirect from the ActionMapping over to a ResourceMapping?  If I specify a renderparameter in the response of the ActionMapping, it will direct me to a RenderRequest.

So, the flow that I want is: RenderMapping -> jQuery dialog -> Resource URL -> Display html in jQuery dialog.  Complete the form -> Submit -> ActionMapping ->

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Your problem is that you don't know how to generate the right action url when you send back the html of your form in the ResourceMapping method ?

Comment: Yeah.  Basically, the ActionMapping has options for returning you to a RenderResponse.  But, in this case, I want to return the response without any other portal assets (a resource response).

Comment: Why not submitting your form to a ResourceMapping ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974797/modelattribute-spring-mvc-portlets-and-ajax-form-submit

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  That was what I was going to try next.  I just thought someone may have figured out a way to do it with an ActionMapping or if I was just doing something wrong.  I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

It is standard way when after each action phase (ActionMapping) comes render phase (RenderMapping) of the portlet. Therefore it is correct, if you specify a renderparameter in the response of the ActionMapping, it will direct you to a RenderRequest. It is according to the specification and you cannot change it. So there is no way to call resource phase (ResourceMapping) after finishing action phase.